# If $\measuredangle A > \measuredangle B$, then $\sin\measuredangle A > \sin\measuredangle B$ in an acute triangle. Why?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

In an acute triangle, if $\measuredangle A > \measuredangle B$, then $\sin\measuredangle A > \sin\measuredangle B$. Why is this true?

Comment: See https://www.mathopenref.com/triggraphsine.html as discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851112/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-sine-cosine-and-tangent-of-an-obtuse-angle/3851143#3851143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, all angles in an acute triangle are less than 90 degrees.
Therefore, from the graph of $\displaystyle \sin( x)$, we know that it is an increasing function on the interval $\displaystyle \left[ 0,\frac{\pi }{2}\right]$.
[image]

Therefore, as $\displaystyle \sin( x)$ is an increasing function, if $\displaystyle a\  >b$, then $\displaystyle \sin( a)  >\sin( b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you define sine, this picture may already help you through:

[image]

Comment: Right now I'm only thinking of it in terms of the ratios, sin = opposite / hypotenuse, I'm not very familiar with the unit circle definition.

Answer (score 2):

The result follows because $0 \leq A < B \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\sin$ is a strictly increasing function on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. The latter can be shown from the definition of $\sin$ and Pythagoras's theorem, or some calculus.